# Rest Framework Seralizer always returns false from is_valid

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am setting up a database of cars inventory and trying to filling it up with json data provided by an api. What is wrong with my seralizer?

This is on Window, Django2 and Sqlite database, and Python3.
Please help me to get the desired output ! Thanks

seralizer.py

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import SavedInventory

    class EmbedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = SavedInventory
            fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```py
    vin = form.cleaned_data['vin']
                links={"X-RapidAPI-Host":settings.VINDECODERHOST, "X-RapidAPI-Key": settings.VINDECODERKEY}
                r = requests.get("https://vindecoder.p.rapidapi.com/decode_vin?vin="+ vin + "&key=" + settings.VINDECODERKEY)
                json = r.json()
                serializer = EmbedSerializer(data=json)
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    saved = serializer.save()
                    return render(request, 'saved.html', {'embed': embed})
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('<h1>ERROR Seralizer</h1>')
```

Sqlite Based
models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class SavedInventory(models.Model):
    vin = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    trim_level = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    engine = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    style = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    steering_type = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    anti_brake_system = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    tank_size = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    overall_height = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    overall_length = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    overall_width = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    highway_mileage = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city_mileage = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

JSON Response from API

```
   "success":true,
   "specification":{  
      "vin":"JNKCA31A61T027494",
      "year":"2001",
      "make":"Infiniti",
      "model":"I30",
      "trim_level":"Touring",
      "engine":"3.0L V6 DOHC 24V",
      "style":"Sedan (4-Door)",
      "made_in":"Japan",
      "steering_type":"R&P",
      "anti_brake_system":"4-Wheel ABS",
      "tank_size":null,
      "overall_height":"56.50 inches",
      "overall_length":"193.70 inches",
      "overall_width":"70.20 inches",
      "standard_seating":"5",
      "optional_seating":null,
      "highway_mileage":"28 miles/gallon",
      "city_mileage":"20 miles/gallon",
      "fuel_type":"Gasoline",
      "drive_type":"FWD",
      "transmission":"Automatic",
      "features":[  
         "Air Conditioning",
         "Cruise Control",
         "Power Seat (Driver)",
         "Remote Trunk Release",
         "Anti-theft System",
         "Front Airbags (Driver)",
         "Tachometer"
      ]
   },
   "vin":"JNKCA31A61T027494"
}
```

Comment: Will be good if you can share the SavedInventory Model and add a print to json variable.

Comment: @PradeepAgnihotri I have edited the post with your needs! Please look if u can find the solution

Comment: update code to - serializer = EmbedSerializer(data=json.get('specification', {}))